# Why chrome all time make request for SVG?

Tags: google-chrome, http, svg, cache-control

I'm using SVG like in this case

```
  <svg id="svgs" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <use href="/dpl-iconfont-sprite.svg#align_right"></use>
  </svg>
```

when I have headers `cache-control: no-cache` and render the same icon several times, on each render Chrome make request to server(I think it's validation request for cache), but it doesn't happen when I use images.
Why is it happening and what difference between using img and svg?

Answer (score 0):

Try add cache control to your server, this fix to me.